# Call view with ajax javascript in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to call `Action` to open up my `Index View` by Ajax Javascript, but it does not load target view. Before I use ajax I called action like this that work properly:

```
<a class="btn btn-orange" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Booking", new { area = "Portal" })">انتخاب</a>
```

But I need to call with javascript Ajax and when I transfer that to this :

```
<a class="btn btn-orange" onclick="Booking(@Json.Encode(item))">انتخاب</a>
```

I faced this problem that it does not load page. 
This is my ajax code:

```
function Booking(obj) {
    var schedulingViewModel = {
    };
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            schedulingViewModel[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Portal/Booking',
        type: 'post',
        data: schedulingViewModel,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Data: ' + data);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
}
```

And this s my BookingController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Tranship.ViewModel;

namespace Tranship.UI.Areas.Portal.Controllers
{
    public class BookingController: Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ScheduleViewModel schedulingViewModel)
        {
            return View("Index", schedulingViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view with IEnumerable model that I want to send an Item of that to action:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tranship.ViewModel.ScheduleViewModel>
<div class="pg-search-form">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="list-block main-block f-list-block dashboard-listing booking-listing">
            <div class="list-content">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dash-list-icon booking-list-date">
                                <div class="b-date">
                                    <h3>@item.DepartureDay</h3>
                                    <p>@item.DepartureMonth</p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="dash-list-text booking-list-detail">
                                <h3>@item.Origin به @item.Destination</h3>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled booking-info">
                                    <li>@item.DepartureDate<span>تاریخ رفت :</span></li>
                                    <li>@item.ArrivalDate<span>تاریخ برگشت :</span></li>
                                    <li>@item.Adult نفر<span>تعداد :</span></li>

                                </ul>

                            </td>
                            <td class="dash-list-btn">
                                <a class="btn btn-orange" onclick="BookingMethod(@Json.Encode(item))">انتخاب</a>
                                @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-orange">انتخاب</button>*@
                                @*<a class="btn btn-orange" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Booking", new { area = "Portal" })">انتخاب</a>*@
                                <div id="price">@item.Price تومان</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- end list-content -->
        </div>
    }
    <div class="pages">
        <ol class="pagination">
            <li><a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <!-- end pages -->
</div>
```

In fact ajax return correct HTML but I couldn't find why it does not redirect to target view.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. Ajax calls cannot redirect. If you want to redirect, then DO NOT use ajax.

Comment: what should I do? I need to send my model in the loop.  I could not use @HTML.Beginform and submit that

Comment: Why not? What makes you think you need to _send my model in the loop_? (you don't if you have generated your view correctly)

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke- please take a look at my view it is a collection and I want to the item that user click on it

Comment: Could you possibly leave a sample post?

Comment: There are no editable controls in your view. What is the point of this? Why would you send back the original data back to the server?

Comment: Because these are some suggestions that user must select one of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183820/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sasan-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window.location()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) is used to redirect from one page to another page.

After Successful ajax request write that code.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Portal/Booking',
    type: 'post',
    data: schedulingViewModel,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Data: ' + data);
        window.location = "/Booking/Index";
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale - It worked but how can I sent my Model as json with window.location??

Comment: @SasanK You are more than welcome, I'm glad I could help.